# Dependency injection in service class of custom angular library throwing error

Tags: dependency-injection, angular8, angular-library

I have created a custom angular library. It has a service class that uses HTTPClientModule for backend connectivity, following is the part of code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NLService {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

createRequest(data) : Observable<any>{
    console.log(this.http);
    return this.http.post<any>('someURL' + '/create',data,this.httpOptions);

  }
```

After doing ng build and installing this library in another project, I am making a call to backend(to the above service) from component

```
async create(){

  await NLComponent.prototype.createRequest(createData);

}
```

On hitting this , I get the below error:

core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined.

Can anyone help? I have already imported HTTPClientModule in module file of library.

Comment: could you solve this issue, I have a similar problem and don't know how to solve it.